# Using Razer Synapse, can I lower my mouse sensitivity while aiming?

Tags: hardware, mouse, razer-synapse

When I press my right mouse button (RMB), I would like to:

1. Have my character aim their weapon (the default behavior)
2. Have the DPI of my mouse lowered

When I release RMB, I would like to stop aiming and have the DPI return to normal.  How can I set this up using the Razer Synapse software (I'm only using a Deathadder, if it matters).

Comment: I had a mouse with such feature, pressing a button to lower the DPI to aim. I found it very useless, also depending on the game you're playing, it might be doable in-game, what's the game ?

Comment: @Иво, In this case, _Rise of the Tomb Raider_, but I'd like to be able to adjust for any game with aiming.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the software mentioned in the post, but perhaps a different mouse may be needed.  For instance, one [like this](https://m.newegg.com/Product/index?itemnumber=N82E16826104674&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-Mobile&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-Mobile-_-pla-_-Gaming+Mice-_-N82E16826104674&gclid=Cj0KEQjwr7S-BRD96_uw9JK8uNABEiQAujbffIU5gDnQnymJu5N5lYWBCz7pPn3SFDg3FQi5puZuIF8aAkrA8P8HAQ&gclsrc=aw.ds).  I personally use this mouse, and it has what LG calls a G-shift button which can be programmed to lower the DPI (as well as much more) when pressed. I love it for precision work and gaming.

Answer (score 1):

Razer Synapse allows you to assign the side buttons to either clutch or toggle through sensitivities, which for the Deathadder 2013 goes from 100 DPI to 6400 DPI.

Here are some pictures to clarify:

[image]

[image]